# Can we setup an app that can subscribe to the changes on Microsoft Teams Channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to integrate Microsoft Teams in our application, and our application should get notification when the message is posted inside the Teams channel.

I found we can setup a notification for changes in user data in official documentations (
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks). As like this, can we step a notification for changes of Teams Channel?

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [Add custom bot to Microsoft Teams with outgoing webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook).

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT, if i use webhook users are required to **@mention** the name of the outgoing webhook. I need to receive notifications of message posted in channel without using mention.

I found we can set up notifications for changes in user data as per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks). But it didn't find specific information related to Teams channel. Can we setup an app that can subscribe to changes on the Teams Channel to receive the notification?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT, In the mean time [Mio](https://m.io/) has the functionality to receive message posted Teams channel and show it in slack channel. They are not mentioning bot or webhook to forward message to external system (slack channel). I'm also looking for similar kind of functionality where user simply post message in Channel and my external system would receive notification.

Comment: You can go with the [Mio](https://m.io/). Currently there is no other way to achieve this.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT, I'm looking to develop own system as like Mio. What could be their back-end logic?

Comment: Mio support Team Authorization, Channel and User mapping and message routing. Please take a look at  [How Mio works](https://m.io/how-it-works).